# How do I fine tune my Open AI model using the API?

Tags: php, openai-api

I wanted to ask if I am doing something wrong , because I want to "teach" my previously created davinci model , by sending a data packet to it at url (that chatGPT gave me)

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/models/".$model_name.":fine-tune
```

Where $model_name is variable for my name

```
"davinci:ft-hotres-sp-ka-with-limited-responsibility-ci-2023-03-16-10-46-11"
```

But response is always

> Not allowed to POST on /v1/models/davinci:ft-hotres-sp-ka-with-limited-responsibility-ci-2023-03-16-10-46-11:fine-tune. (HINT: Perhaps you meant to use a different HTTP method?)

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
 $model_name = 'davinci:ft-hotres-sp-ka-z-ograniczon-odpowiedzialno-ci-2023-03-16-10-46-11';
        $api_key = 'key';
        $openai_url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/models/' . $model_name;

        $training_data_path = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $training_data = file_get_contents($training_data_path);

        $data = array(
            'prompt' => $training_data,
            'n' => 1
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.openai.com/v1/models/".$model_name.":fine-tune");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization: Bearer " . $api_key,
        ));

        // wykonanie zapytania
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // obsługa odpowiedzi
        if (!$response) {
            echo 'Błąd: brak odpowiedzi z serwera OpenAI.';
        } else {
            $response_data = json_decode($response, true);
            if (isset($response_data['error'])) {
                echo 'Błąd: ' . $response_data['error']['message'];
            } else {
                echo 'Sukces: model jest aktualnie trenowany.';
            }
        }
```

I've tried many resolutions based on help from ChatGPT and documentation at OpenAI

Comment: Never used it before but [this documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/models/list) suggests the appropriate method is GET??

Comment: Yes , for listing models . I want to teach my existing model

Comment: Did you create your model with the API? The [API reference](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/models) only lists two endpoints related to models: List Models and Retrieve Models. It doesn't look like POST is allowed/accepted.